# Submitting a Java program which implements the Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: java, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I would like some feedback on a Java program which implements the Sieve of Eratosthenes to find prime numbers.  Some of the 'features' I've included in the program include:

It uses a `BitSet` for identifying primes.  What really gets checked is whether the index of any bit is prime.  This eliminates the need to store the primes as actual numbers.

The program runs fairly quickly.  It can identify over 105 million primes in about 44 seconds on my iMac.

I implemented a timer because I was tired of watching the clock.

I know I probably haven't done everything 'by the book' with this, so let me know where you think I need to do some cleanup.

```
//package Eratosthenes5;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.BitSet;

public class Eratosthenes5 {

    // This uses a BitSet instead of a boolean array to see
    // if this saves any memory. It enables me to test approx.
    // 8x as many numbers. 109905151 is no longer my max.
    // The highest number I've reached, so far, is around 879,400,000.
    //
    // After giving more memory to the app, I can check for primes up
    // to around 2 billion. I've not determined the upper limit, but
    // I suspect it is the java max integer size. It finds almost
    // 100 million primes in under a minute.
    // 2^31 = 2,147,483,648

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int maxSize = 1;
        int maxNumber;
        int maxSearch;
        int primeCount;
        int maxPrime;
        String name;
        name = getTheMaxNumber();
        while (name.compareTo("1") != 0) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            maxSize = Integer.parseInt(name);
            maxNumber = maxSize + 1;
            maxSearch = (int) java.lang.Math.sqrt(maxNumber);
            primeCount = 1; // Start the count at 1 because 2 is prime and we'll
                            // start at 3
            maxPrime = -1;
            // use a BitSet array to maximize how many primes can be found
            BitSet numbList = new BitSet(maxNumber);

            numbList.set(0, maxNumber - 1, true); // set all bits to true

            numbList.clear(0);
            numbList.clear(1);

            // clear the even numbers (except 2, it's prime)
            for (long k = 4; k <= maxSize; k += 2) {
                numbList.clear((int) k);
            }

            // sieve out the non-primes
            for (int k = 3; k < maxSearch; k += 2) {
                if (numbList.get(k)) {
                    sieveTheRest(k, numbList, maxSize);
                }
            }

            // Count the primes
            for (int k = 3; k <= maxSize; k += 2) {
                if (numbList.get(k)) {
                    maxPrime = k;
                    primeCount += 1;
                    if (primeCount % 1000000 == 0) {
                        System.out.format("the "
                                + ((primeCount / 1000000 < 100) ? " " : "")
                                + ((primeCount / 1000000 < 10) ? " " : "")
                                + primeCount / 1000000
                                + " millionth prime is: %,11d%n", maxPrime);
                    }
                }
            }

            // we're done
            System.out.format("\nMy integer from beg: %,11d%n", Integer
                    .parseInt(name));
            System.out.format("array size         : %,11d%n", maxNumber);
            System.out.format("prime count        : %,11d%n", numbList
                    .cardinality());
            System.out.format("largest prime found: %,11d%n", maxPrime);
            System.out.format("max factor         : %,11d%n \n", maxSearch);

            long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("That took " + (stopTime - startTime) / 1000.0
                    + " seconds");

            name = getTheMaxNumber();
        }// end of while
        System.out.println("\nEnd of program");

    }// End of method Main
    /**
     * 
     * @return Passes back a string holding the maximum number to check
     */
    static String getTheMaxNumber() {
        BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        String bigNumber = "";
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer value (1 to quit): ");
        try {
            bigNumber = dataIn.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
        return bigNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @param myPrime
     *            The latest prime to be found.
     * @param theBitSet
     *            The BitSet holding the prime flags
     * @param maxSize
     *            The largest index in the BitSet
     */
    static void sieveTheRest(int myPrime, BitSet theBitSet, int maxSize) {
        for (long k = myPrime * myPrime; k <= maxSize; k += 2 * myPrime) {
            theBitSet.clear((int) k);
        }
    }

}// End of Class eratosthenes5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have implemented it correctly from a complexity point of view, which is good.

I noticed a few things you could improve:

- Why would a `getTheMaxNumber` method return a `String`? Why is the string called `name`?
- You have a two page `main()` function, which then calls `sieveTheRest`. It would be nicer to just put all the sieving related code in one method.
- You can also refactor your reporting code into a method of its own, this will make the `main` method more readable.
- You don't win much performance by making `2` a special case. It just makes the code less readable.
- You only find primes up to `sqrt(name)`, why not all the way up to `name`?

**Update:**

Here is a very small implementation, which will `set` all primes in `[0, maxNumber)`.

```
BitSet numbList = new BitSet(maxNumber);
numbList.set(2, maxNumber);
for (int i = 2; i < maxNumber; i++)
    if (numbList.get(i))
        for (int j = 2*i; j < maxNumber; j+=i)
            numbList.clear(j);
```

If you want the above to only run the outer loop up till `sqrt(maxNumber)`, just change the first loop to `for (int i = 2; i*i < maxNumber; i++)`. Just remember that any added complexity increases the chance of bugs.

Comment: I only went up to the sqrt(name) because when you reach that point all of the primes in the bitset have been found and there's no reason to go farther.  You can then just use them or, in my case, report them.  Making 2 a special case wasn't done for performance reasons, it was done simply because I didn't want to burden my sieve method with what I considered a special case which needed to be handled differently from all the other primes.

Comment: Fair enough, but try to benchmark the code without it. The original 'Sieve of Eratosthenes' doesn't use this 'optimization', because the large numbers are passed so quickly, that their contribution to the running time should be insignificant.

Comment: I tried benchmarking the code without the loop that marks all of the multiples of 2.  It only ran about 5% slower, but I didn't like the way the code looked.  In my view, the code is MORE readable this way.  As far as what the 'original' Sieve of Eratosthenes uses, well, I wouldn't know, but I suspect that MOST of the optimizations I've added aren't in it.  I still think I've stayed true to the intent of the algorithm.

Comment: After working on this code for a while.  I've found that it's far more 'fragile' than I would like.  Indicates to me that there's something(s) I've overlooked.

Comment: Ok, when I use my logic and try to let the sieve run up to 'name', it starts giving me incorrect results.  It's like the index is 'wrapping' and clearing some previously marked primes.  I guess I'll stay with my stopping point of sqrt(name) since that appears to give correct results up to the max integer I can give it.  This is also about 40% faster than going all the way up to 'name'.

Comment: I'm can't quite see why it would start wrapping around, but I've written a short implementation you can use for comparison. (Warning: I have only proved it correct, not tested it,  ;-))

Comment: Thank you for the input.  I guess I don't understand where you're headed with that code.  When I ran your code, it looks like all it does is turn the bits for all of the even numbers on (multiple times, in fact).  All of the odd locations are left as 0.  So, I am confused as to how this is supposed to help.  I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just saying I'm not sure how to apply what you gave me to the program.

Comment: Oops, I told you I hadn't tested it ;-) How about now?

Comment: Much better, @Thomas, I'll work this into my code and let you know the result.

Comment: Ok, running your code for an input of 1000000000 (1 billion) finds 50,847,534 primes in 58 seconds.  My code, running on the same billion finds the same number of primes in 17 seconds.  I'd say that this shows that my optimizations are significant.  I didn't try selectively removing any of my optimizations, though, to see which are most responsible for the difference.  I WILL say that your code is very clean, though, and that's a nice thing.

Comment: I added as much of 'my' optimizations as I could to your code and got the run time of 'our' code down to very nearly the same as my code (18 seconds versus 17 seconds for my code).

Comment: You can also start the second loop from `i*i`: `for (int j = i*i; j < maxNumber; j+=i)`

Comment: I tried that and got an index out of bounds error.  It looked like something was going way past the end of the BitSet.  I didn't go any farther with it.  The code is pretty much reverted to your original setup with some supporting code to do timing and printing.  Just as an aside, shouldn't it be j+=2*i ?

Comment: Hummm, no, that probably won't work because we don't have a separate loop to eliminate the even numbers.  Dang, keep getting caught in my own optimizations.

Comment: It shouldn't give out of bounds, since we still have `j < maxNumber`. Works well for me anyway.

Comment: Did you actually try it for 1 billion?  It works for me, too, up to 100 million.  As soon as I step up to 1 billion, I get the index out of bounds error.  The ONLY thing I changed was the 'i+i' to 'i*i' in the second loop.  The 'i+i' code works just fine for 1 billion.

Comment: Right, if you use an int that'll overflow. Try with 64bit precision.

Comment: I changed the code to use long numbers where necessary and this seems to have done the trick.  I did have to change the outer loop a little bit to make it all work.  With my optimizations, your code runs in about the same time as mine and it will work with numbers as high as 2 billion without failing.  The only difference I can find is that I am able to input 2147483646 as my largest index for the BitSet.  When I try to do that with your code, I'm back to index errors.  I'm getting tired of trying to reconcile these programs but I've proved, at least to myself, that our algorithms match up.

Comment: Whether it is fast enough is a matter of your use case. There are other algorithm sieves that are faster than Eratosthenes, but most of the time it works nicely.

Comment: What I like about the Sieve of Eratosthenes, though, is its 'elegant simplicity'.  It doesn't take a lot of thought to understand that it 'just works'.  Granted that there may be some inherent limitations that go along with it, it's very easy to implement and test and works pretty quickly for a nice range of numbers.  I'll do some more 'clean up' on the code and see what I can do about posting my 'final' answer. Thank you for your help and patience.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at your code and I find it very enlightening since I've never used  `BitSet`.

I was wondering how the result could be saved in an external file for checking primality of numbers (up to ~800.000.000), which I guess would occupy around 100MB (around 100.000.000 bytes).

About the upper limit of the `BitSet`, I also think that it's the Java max integer size, since the constructor takes an integer.  Maybe for larger sizes it could be implemented with an array of `BitSet` (first approach), even though the positions wouldn't be immediate then?  Maybe I'll take a look at that after exams and let you know if I get to something solid.

Comment: Well, one possibility would be to just save the BitSet and read it in.  It can currently identify around 105 million primes going up into the 2,000,000,000 neighborhood which would be enough for what you've stated.  To verify a prime you can just check the BitSet location for that number.  Unfortunately, how to save and restore the bitset is a little beyond me.  You could use this code to regen it each time, I suppose, but would depend on your implementation.  Good luck with it.

Comment: Also, @Guimo, you CAN save substantial space in the BitSet by simply using it to represent the odd integers above 1.  This can save a small amount of sieving time because you never have to sieve out the even numbers larger than 4.  My final code runs in about 33 seconds, finding the primes up to 2,147,483,647.  This is about 4 seconds faster than my version that represents all of the integers and has to filter the even numbers out.  The big savings is that the new BitSet is about half the size (around 128 mb versus 256 mb).  The numbers are messier, though, and harder to work with.